# How to disable ipv6 from my docker bridge and docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm currently using docker 20.10.9 version.
My host is enabled with ipv4 but when I run the docker I get the following error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uXh8.png)

How can we disable ipv6 by default? as I have ipv4 enabled on my host